# Making LHS of Windows explorer reflect selected item location in RHS

Tags: windows-7

In the Windows Explorer for Windows 7, the treeview at the left hand side doesn't always reflect "where you are" in the right hand side and bread crumb trail at the top.

I find this annoying, since I have to manually expand out LHS treeview folders until it matches the RHS.

How do you force the LHS of Win Explorer display the same location as the RHS does?

This question may also apply to Vista, but I wouldn't know - I have never used it :)

Comment: I tried right clicking and saying "Expand to current folder" - seems to have no effect

Comment: Good question, this is my only real issue with Windows 7, so I'm interested to see if there is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see.

Well, right clicking in the LHS treeview area (in a blank part, underneath the entire tree listing is a safe place to click..) and selecting "Expand to current folder" **does** work, but if the folder is a hidden folder, its not going to show in the LHS treeview.

Turn on display of hidden files and folders, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst changing some file view options I noticed by chance the actual option to resolve this issue.

On the Organize drop down menu in explorer windows, select the "Folder and search options" option. On the General tab (which is the first shown), in the Navigation pane group box check the second option "Automatically expand to current folder".